# Delete item from SQLite and then RecyclerView

Tags: android

**my sqlite delete code**

```
public void deleteItem(int position) {
   SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase(); 
   db.delete(TABLE_PLACE, ID + "=?" + position , null); 
}
```

---

---

**recyclerview**

```
@Override
    public void onItemRemoved(int position) {
        places.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

How can i delete any row from `SQLite` database and then delete it from `RecyclerView` too

Comment: SO what is the question here ?

Comment: i dont now what code to write  in the onItemRemoved to removr from db

Comment: i calling the db in the onItemRemoved and nothing apen

Comment: Man, you need to learn how to ask SO questions... A bit of formatting, much better English and you're ready.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem. The problem with passing the position to your SQLite DELETE statement is that the item's position index always changes while your databases ID stays the same.

Instead of relying on the row ID (assuming that's your auto increment primary key) to match up with the position you are passing you should create another column in your table; let's call it item_index. Every time you create a new row in your database you should first set the item_index value(integer) to the size of your ArrayList (like the one you use to inflate your recyclerview) this will make the first row's item_index = 0, the second = 1, third = 2, and so on.

```
//EXAMPLE:
YourDataBaseHelper yourDataBaseHelper = new YourDataBaseHelper(/*proper parameters*/);//your database Class object
YourData yourData = new YourData(); //your setters and getters Class object
ArrayList<YourData> yourDataCounter = yourDataBaseHelper.getItems();//yourDataBaseHelper.whatever method you use to populate your ArrayList
yourData.set_itemIndex(yourDataCounter.size());
yourDataBaseHelper.addRow(yourData);//whatever method you use to insert rows
```

Now we still have the problem with the item_index and the position value that's being passed not matching up. You can solve this by going into your dataBaseHelper class and in your deleteItem method you can do the following:

```
        public void deleteItem(int position){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PLACE + " WHERE " +
                ITEM_INDEX + " = " + position + ";");
        db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_PLACE + " SET " + ITEM_INDEX + " = " +
                ITEM_INDEX + " -1 " + " WHERE " + ITEM_INDEX + " > " + position + ";");
        db.close();
    }
```

The UPDATE statement is important because it ensures that your item_index value always matches your recyclerview position simply by subtracting 1 by all the values in your item_index column that is greater than the value of the position that was passed.

All of this can be kicked off in your Adapter Class in a method called itemRemoved which can be called by an onClick method:

```
private ArrayList<YourData> yourData = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;

public YourAdapter(ArrayList<YourData> yourData, Context context) {
    this.yourData = yourData;
    this.context = context;
}

public void itemRemoved(int position) {
    YourDataBaseHelper yourDataBaseHelper = new YourDataBaseHelper(/*proper parameters*/);

    yourData.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);

    yourDataBaseHelper.deleteItem(position);

}
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: You save me! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this way :

```
public void deleteItem(int position) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase(); 
    db.delete(TABLE_PLACE, ID + "=?" + position , null);
    //you can try theese following 2 lines to delete
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE "+COlUMN_NAME+"='"+value+"'");
    db.close();
    places.remove(position);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //or like this
    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
```

Comment: this deleteItem in db ?

Comment: Firstly delete item in db, then remove item from your arraylist , then notify.

Comment: how can i call adapter in db ?

Comment: no , like this way  : put this method where is your recyclerview and adapter located. For example in MainActivity. When you trigger this method you can delete your db item and recyclerview item both.

Comment: OK , and in my db what method is gone be